# How to JOIN ON when both tables contain NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, null

I am doing an outer join of 2 tables on 2 columns. The join should happen if table1.column1=table2.column1 and table1.column2=table2.column2.  Since column2 is allowed to be  contain null, the join fails whenever the value is null, since *null* is not equal to *null* (only a computer scientist could love that).

The workaround I came up with is:

```
select table1.column1,table1.colunn1,table2.column1,table2.column2 from 
table1 
left join table2 
       on table1.column1=table2.column1 
       and if(table1.column2 is null,table2.column2 is null, table1.column2=table2.column2)
```

This works correctly, but there must be a better way?

Comment: You don't have to be a computer scientist to understand why `NULL = NULL` cannot really result in `TRUE`. Just consider the following example. The author of *Hamlet* is Shakespeare, the author of *Macbeth* is Shakespeare too. On the other hand, the author of *Epic of Gilgamesh* is unknown (NULL), and so is the author of *Mahabharata*. Now, we *can* say about the former two books that their author is the same person, but we can't say that about the other two books.

Comment: @AndriyM: Good point. Although clearly for database usage, many people don't really think that way about their data - hence the need for mysql to include a null-safe comparison operator. My own feeling is that should be the default, and let people choose the strict null operator explicitly.

Comment: In giving your specification you are not clear about when you mean normal equality & when you mean SQL "equality". You could maybe use "is" for normal equality. PS Another problem is that the normal (mathematical & cs) term "value" is also appropriated by SQL rhetoric where the fuzzy unhelpful claim is made that SQL null is not a value. Of course it's a value, it's just one treated specially by SQL operators like SQL "equality".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the MySQL [null-safe comparison operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) `<=>`:

```
SELECT    t1.column1, t1.column2, t2.column1, t2.column2 
FROM      table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
       ON t1.column1 = t2.column1 AND t1.column2 <=> t2.column2
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be just `t1.column2 <=> t2.column2`? Once you use that comparison, the other one becomes superfluous, unless I'm missing something (haven't used `<=>` often, to say the least).

Comment: @AndriyM, there's two different columns the OP is wanting to join on: `column1` AND `column2`. `column2` is allowed to contain `NULL`, but we still want to retain the join condition on `column1`.

Comment: Ah, yes, the columns are different, I missed that. Sorry.

Comment: I didn't know about the null-safe comparison operator.  Exactly what I needed, and it works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would do `LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.column1 = table2.column1 OR (table1.column1 IS NULL AND table2.column1 IS NULL)`. I don't know for sure if that would work or not.

(By the way, nulls are not values.)

Answer (score 0):

Because `NULL`s exist in the source data, default the values using `COALESCE` (or `NVL` in Oracle) before being used in the `LEFT JOIN`, to allow the `WHERE` clause to work as expected. The `'DEFAULT_VALUE'` can be whatever you choose, depending on the datatype. This method is effective because it removed confusion and allows the expressions to work properly, without `NULL`s getting in the way.

Using inline views:

```
select table1.column1,table1.column1,table2.column1,table2.column2
from
(
    select
    table1.column1
    coalesce(table1.column2,'DEFAULT_VALUE') as column2
    from table1
) t1
left join (
            select
            table2.column1
            coalesce(table2.column2,'DEFAULT_VALUE') as column2
            from table2
          ) t2
       on t2.column1 = t1.column1
      and t2.column2 = t1.column2;
```

Or using CTEs:

```
with t1 as
(
    select
    table1.column1
    coalesce(table1.column2,'DEFAULT_VALUE') as column2
    from table1
),
t2 as
(
    select
    table2.column1
    coalesce(table2.column2,'DEFAULT_VALUE') as column2
    from table2
)     
select table1.column1,table1.column1,table2.column1,table2.column2
from t1
left join t2
       on t2.column1 = t1.column1
      and t2.column2 = t1.column2;
```