# Backend returns error when left join fields are empty

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, query-builder, api-platform.com

I have a query to return company details, but if the field used for left join is empty query returns error .How to solve this?

I tried,

```
->leftJoin('company.field1', 'field1')
->leftJoin('company.field2', 'field2')
->andWhere('company.field1!= :empty')->setParameter('empty', serialize([]))
        ->andWhere('company.field2!= :empty')->setParameter('empty', 
serialize([]));
```

This will return all companies with non empty field1 and field2 only.But i want all companies with empty/non-empty field1&field2.This fields field1 and field2 are not mandatory fields to add from front end.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you provide an example of your entities?

Comment: check this out for how to handle null values and try to adapt to your situation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11566476/4716084

Comment: `But i want all companies with empty/non-empty field1&field2` - So, the value doesn't matter. Why include it in where statements? And possibly use `orWhere` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LeftJoin` accept null values.

```php
$queryBuilder
  ->leftJoin('company.field1', 'field1')
  ->leftJoin('company.field2', 'field2')
  ->where('company.field1 is null')
  ->andWhere('company.field2 is null');
```

This will return all companies where field1 and field2 are empty only. 
(The two fields must be empty to be returned).
*(Perhaps you should try with `=` instead of the keyword `is`)*